# Calling a Apex method within a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, invocable-method

In my Class I have this method

```
global class Queue{

    @InvocableMethod

    public static void send(List<ListRequests> requests){...}

    }
```

In my trigger I initialize the class, call the method, but it is throwing the error of "Method does not exist or incorrect signature".

```
trigger CallBack on Task (before insert) {

    Queue sendToQueue = new Queue();

    List<String> lead = new List<String>();

    sendToQueue.send(lead);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invocable method expects this argument

```
send(List<ListRequests> requests)
```

Whereas you are sending `list<String>` into this `sendToQueue.send(lead);`

Also, `Queue` is a reserve object. So better to use different name of class.

Other thing is, since method is `static`, use `ClassName.methodName()` for calling. Don't use instance of the Class to call the method.

Comment: so  I need to initialize a new List of ListRequests in the trigger and pass that that into the callout

Comment: yes, you need to work like that way

Comment: I am having a problem when I initialize a new ListRequests in the trigger.  I am setting the list as List<ListRequests> requests = new ListRequests(); but the error is invalid type .    Do I need to specify the type of list as List<Queue.ListRequests> requests = new Queue.ListRequests();

Comment: then post your code with a separate question